# google drive api download file response body

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

[response body img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/welxN.png)

```
        window.gapi.client.drive.files.get({
            fileId,
            alt: 'media'
        })
```

I download image/jpeg using gapi lib and want to convert body response to data url so I can insert it to img src on my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve an image file from Google Drive.
- You want to convert the retrieved image file to the data URL.
- You want to achieve this using gapi with Javascript.
- You have already been able to retrieve the image file using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, consider this answer.

In this answer, I converted the binary data from Google Drive to the base64 data using `btoa()`.

#### Sample script:

```
const fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID.

gapi.client.drive.files.get({
  fileId,
  alt: 'media'
}).then(res => {
  const dataUrl = `data:${res.headers["Content-Type"]};base64,${btoa(res.body)}`;
  console.log(dataUrl);  // You can see the converted data URL at console.
});
```

or

```
const fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID.

window.gapi.client.drive.files.get({
  fileId,
  alt: 'media'
}).then(res => {
  const dataUrl = `data:${res.headers["Content-Type"]};base64,${window.btoa(res.body)}`;
  console.log(dataUrl);  // You can see the converted data URL at console.
});
```

or

```
const fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID.

window.gapi.client.drive.files.get({
  fileId,
  alt: 'media'
}).then(function(res) {
  const dataUrl = "data:" + res.headers["Content-Type"] + ";base64," + window.btoa(res.body);
  console.log(dataUrl);
});
```

#### Note:

For example, when the following script is used, the data URL can be put to HTML as an image.

```
    var e = document.createElement("img");
    e.setAttribute("src", dataUrl);
    document.getElementById("image").appendChild(e);
```

#### References:

- [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa)
- [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)